# Image manipulation code in MATLAB (corner detection)

Tags: image, matlab

I'd like to know exactly how this line of code works

```
corners = (m==n)&(n>threshold);
```

It's in a piece of code I'm using and I want to understand it. Basically, m and n are both equal-sized images, and "threshold" is a decimal value.

To understand the context, a segment of the code is below.

```
% compute the m cornerness measure
m = (ix2s.*iy2s - ixys.^2) - 0.04*(ix2s+iy2s).^2;

% perform non-maximal suppression using ordfilt2
n = ordfilt2(m, radius^2, ones([radius radius]));

% display corner spots
corners = (m==n)&(n>threshold);

% superimpose corners
Q = corners+im;
Q(Q>1) = 1;
C = repmat(im,[1 1 3]);
C(:,:,1) = Q;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, n is the max of m ("cornerness measure") for the vicinity, so the line means - "if m is the local maximum and large enough(larger than threshold), then this is probably a corner", it could  have arguably been more readable as:

```
corners = (m==n)&(m>threshold);
```

Comment: so just to break it down,
m==n

checks m for equivalency to n in every slot m(:,:) and n(:,:) in the array, marking 1 if true. And this will only happen at local maximums because that is the definition of n relative to m.

Then check to see that the equivalent values are greater than the threshold value and if that is also true, then return 1 into corners.

Is the above correct? Regarding the dimensions of corners, MATLAB automatically gives it the dimensions of both m and n, correct? What if m and n had been different values? I'm guessing the statement would then be invalid?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you explanation is correct. The program calculates m on the first line and n on the second, the outside parameters are the radius (the size of the local area) and the threshold (more or less - our preference level between false positives and false negatives).

Answer (score 1):

You should read more about [Harris corner detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_.26_Stephens_.2F_Plessey_corner_detection_algorithm). Taken from Wikipedia:

[image]

This line is implementation of the function mentioned above. It is used to detect corners.